# How do you make more than one onMapLoadedCallback() requests?

Tags: android, google-maps

In reference to this post - [Detect when Android v2 maps has loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377498/detect-when-android-v2-maps-has-loaded)

I've implemented the onMapLoaded() method in my MainActivity (which implements OnMapLoadedCallback) as such:

```
@Override
public void onMapLoaded(){
    if(...) {
        // move the camera somewhere else on the map
        mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

in an attempt to get onMapLoaded() get called every time the new portion of the map is done loading. Sadly this doesn't work, onMapLoaded() only gets called once. Does anyone know how we're supposed to "request another callback"?

EDIT: Waiting for a response (been a while already) here https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6747

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback.html) your code is correct, so we can only assume this is a bug in the Google Maps Android API v2.

I suggest posting it to the [gmaps-api-issues](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?q=apitype%3DAndroid2).