# Android Google Map - Learn what the current map displayed completely

Tags: java, android, google-maps

How do I know that the current map area, limited screen device, fully loaded? I use animateCamera to move to the desired point and I need to know that after the camera movement, tiles card fully loaded and displayed. 
Thank U!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377498/detect-when-android-v2-maps-has-loaded