# Reveal Map after the Location is found & Map Ready

Tags: android, android-animation, android-location, android-maps-v2

I am trying to achieve this loading with Maps. I have tried loading my animation after the Google Map is created and location is found. But the location loading starts after the animation is completed. How can I achieve the reveal animation after the map camera has navigated to the user's location.

[image: I am trying to achieve this loading with Maps]

I am not using Splash Screen. The animation code is within the MapsActivity.

```
private void setupRevealBackground(){
        final int revealX = (int) (mBackgroundView.getX() + mBackgroundView.getWidth() / 2);
        final int revealY = (int) (mBackgroundView.getY() + mBackgroundView.getHeight() / 2);
        ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = mBackgroundView.getViewTreeObserver();
        if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
            viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    revealActivity(revealX, revealY);
                    mBackgroundView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    protected void revealActivity(int x, int y) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            float finalRadius = (float) (Math.max(mBackgroundView.getWidth(), mBackgroundView.getHeight()) * 1.1);

            // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
            Animator circularReveal = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(mBackgroundView, x, y, 0, finalRadius);
            circularReveal.setDuration(400);
            circularReveal.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

            // make the view visible and start the animation
            circularReveal.start();
            circularReveal.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mBackgroundView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

I am updating the location after the location is found Preference Change Listener.

```
@Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals(Constants.LatitudePref)) {
            Latitude = LocationResultHelper.getSavedLatitude(sharedPreferences);
            Longitude = LocationResultHelper.getSavedLongitude(sharedPreferences);
            if (mPickUpLatLng == null){
                updateMarker(new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude));
            }
        } else if (key.equals(Constants.KEY_LOCATION_UPDATES_REQUESTED)) {
            LocationRequestHelper.getRequesting(this);
        }
    }
```

This is my updateMarker Method after location is found

```
private void updateMarker(LatLng userLocation) {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 16));
        setupRevealBackground();
     }
```

I have tried adding `setupRevealBackground()` method in the `CameraIdleListener` but the method is never called.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18432853/886001) you can use `OnMapLoadedCallback`

When you have a reference to the map set the call back.

```
mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
```

When the `onMapLoaded` event fires take the snapshot.

```
@Override
public void onMapLoaded() {
    // Here you can display your map with animation
}
```

Comment: I have tried but it starts the reveal animation at start when the map is loaded.

Comment: Do you mean when the map has finished loading or when it is still loading?

Comment: When the map has located to the users location.

Comment: isn't that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Map is initially loaded at the default Google Maps region and then redirects to user's location when found.

Comment: what if you wait for The locationmanager to locate the user--> add layout to the view(map and all else)--> animate when map is loaded? may be this approach will help